# Review of code that is composed of multiple, closely related parts

Tags: discussion

So I have finally come up with a set of closely related classes that do what I want:

- Color space (RGB, grayscale) classes with configurable channel width
- Container classes for the colors that support automatic conversions between them and seem (!) to be reasonably fast and reliable.

The code is spread over a number of files (~10), and has grown to considerable size (~25 kB). It includes doxygen comments that produce some bloat (only 50% are real code), and now I'm not sure how to present it here.

Quite a lot of it has been posted here before, so some parts could be considered follow-ups (I have experience with those) and should be treated as such. Now I have a slightly different situation, on a higher level, but I also want to know if I have made some serious mistakes.

My current plan is:

- post each of the major parts in their own question, especially those parts than can be considered follow-ups (and add mutual links). Link to the "meta question" described below.
- post a "meta-question" that is used to address everything that cannot be discussed by just looking at one part. Link to all parts.

This seems to be a good way of asking for low-level advice on the inidvidual parts, and for more high-level advice in the "meta question". Is that a good way of asking for advice in this situation?

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/706/is-it-appropriate-to-post-1k-lines-of-code?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

If you can post it by itself and give us input and expected output (enough to give us a baseline of what the code is doing), I think that it would be fine to post different pieces of the code.

if you can provide input and output, I don't see why you can't post more than one at a time, but keep in mind that you get really cool badges for post good questions daily.

after 5 good question days
after 30 good question days
after 100 good question days

so it wouldn't hurt to space them out either.

I think that you should in small questions, if you look at the user JavaDeveloper, he is the only one with the 100 good question days so far, he has posted almost every part of some application.  I might have read 1 or 2 of his questions. but it seems like he does almost what you speak of, and others can clarify this better for you in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) I am sure

---

I see nothing wrong with what you are proposing either.

having all the pieces come together on one Community Wiki Questions that links them all together sounds like a wonderful idea to me.

---